# Dynamically change ViewPagerIndicator titles

Tags: android, title, viewpagerindicator

My current project uses some `ListFragments` to show rows of data.
The rows get updated dynamically every some seconds. The amount of rows varies with every update and in every `ListFragment`.

I would like to show the amount of rows to the user, and think that the perfect place for that would be next to the `Fragment`'s title in the *ViewPagerIndicator*. I provided a sample image for better comprehension:

[image: Viewpagerindicator]

Sadly I am pretty clueless how to achieve this.
I tried the following:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private int numOne = 0;
    private int numTwo = 0;

    // ...

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "List 1 (" + numOne + ")";
        case 1:
            return "List 2 (" + numTwo + ")";
        default:
            return "";
    }

    public void setNumOne(int num) {
        this.numOne = num;
    }

    public void setNumTwo(int num) {
        this.numTwo = num;
    }
}
```

When I now call the `setNumXXX()` method, nothing happens, until I move between fragments, what seems to trigger the `getPageTitle()` to fire.

My question is: *How can I force an update of the title(s), everytime when the `num` value changes?*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the indicator instance it will redraw itself and grab the new titles.

Comment: Sounds logical, but i guess I am doing it wrong. If i call it on the instance via `mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` nothing changes, neither does it when i call it directly via a method `public void refresh(){ this.notifyDataSetChanged(); }` in the PagerAdaper.

Comment: You should call it in on the `TitlePageIndicator` instance itself, not the adapter.

Comment: Jake Wharton: you deserve a medal :D